# How to install docker properly in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running `jenkins/jenkins` image from dockerhub, I've installed the docker plugin, still not able to find docker inside a pipeline, what am i missing

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Running') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'node:14-alpine'
        }
      }


      steps {
        echo 'preparing the flow'
      }
    }

    stage('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'node:14-alpine'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh """
          npm install
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-5bf3a454/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-5bf3a454/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . hub.docker.com/node:14-alpine
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-dea9bcb7/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-dea9bcb7/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull hub.docker.com/node:14-alpine
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-b25ea3a8/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/multibranch_PR-1@2@tmp/durable-b25ea3a8/script.sh: docker: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is only a utility layer to use docker from your pipelines it does not install docker and still needs access to the docker socket.

Generally there a two ways to achieve this. Install docker inside the jenkins container (with apt) or mount the docker socket of the host inside the container. For the latter you can follow [this](https://medium.com/swlh/quickstart-ci-with-jenkins-and-docker-in-docker-c3f7174ee9ff)